# create a button that emails the google sheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a google sheet that I've created, I have a place where I can put in an email address (in my sheet, it is actually located at cell I6.  What I'm needing to do is create a script that will pull this email address out of I6 and then email the sheet to that email.  I don't want to email every sheet, just that page that has the button I've created.

The main script I have thus far is:

```
function sendemail() {
    MailApp.sendEmail("email address", "subject", "body");
}
```

Where it says "email address", I want it to pull the contents of cell I6.  What is the coding to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Cliff

Comment: What code have you tried? Have you checked the manuals? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Answer (score 1):

Since [UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/) is deprecated, the only option is to assign a script to an image or drawing.

I've followed this tutorial - [Google Spreadsheet Button to Run Scripts](http://googleappscripting.com/google-spreadsheet-button/)

Here is the code snippet:

```
function highFive(){
  Browser.msgBox("High Five!");
}
```

[image]

Once I click the image this will happen:[image]

Also in the tutorial, there is a snippet regarding sending an email with the button:

```
function email(){
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
  var email = rng.getValues()[0];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email[0], email[1], email[2]);
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It really didn't help much.  It only shows me how to pull from the first column.  The email address I use is actually in cell "i6"....I am understanding that I need to create a variable called email, but, I need that to equal the contents of one specific cell...cell "i6" to be exact.  Looking on the internet has completely confused me as some people want to change the discussion to something more complex and/or unrelated (not you...just other threads I've looked at).  Thanks for your help...